# Referring to an executable code block in Quarto

Tags: quarto

Is there a way to label and refer to an executable code chunk in Quarto? I have the following `.qmd` file which when ran through `quarto render` fails to label the executable code chunk.

````
---
title: "My document"
format:
  pdf:
    colorlinks: true
---

```{#lst-fail .R lst-cap="Code Listing"}
x = fail}{
y = fail_harder(((
```

The code in @lst-fail doesn't run. But I can refer to it.

The code in this next block runs but can't be referenced:

```{r}
#| lst-label: lst-data
#| lst-cap: "Make data"
x=1:10
y=runif(10)
```

And if I try then I get (@lst-data) because undefined. Figures are okay though.

```{r}
#| label: fig-xy
#| fig-cap: "x and y"
plot(x,y)
```

The plot is in @fig-xy
````

Output looks like this:

[image]

What I'd like is for the executable code to appear like the first chunk here, a listing, and be referenceable in the body text.

I'm wondering if this is not possible because of the possibility that a code chunk could generate referencable tables or figures within itself, and that would mess things up badly. Or something. I really don't know (and also I can't find any docs on the quarto site about the listing format I've used in the first chunk, I guess its pandoc markdown or something...)

Answer (score 0):

One very naive approach would be link the code block with manual numbering.

````
---
title: "My document"
format:
  pdf:
    colorlinks: true
---

:::{#lst-data}

```{r}
x=1:10
y=runif(10)
```

:::

See [Code Block 1](#lst-data).
````

---

[image: referring executable code blocks]

Comment: I also think this answer can be improved by writing a Lua filter to make things less manual (automatic numbering for executable codes, may be) just as I did in the case of [`nameref`](https://github.com/shafayetShafee/nameref)

Comment: Your output doesn't show which code block is block 1 - that would have to be put in manually? Would it be better to maybe make a sub-sub-sub-section for each code block?

Comment: Yes, that could be another option too.